# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in Express setup

Tags: javascript, html, express

This is my Express setup:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('dist/index.html')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This is the content of `dist`:

[image]

This is the content of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>iStaging LiveTour</title><link href=/static/css/app.b96fc026269e85d4507be6f2804573f0.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.e3bed1667f2313b8b537.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.9a48bc75d44e45d7cd37.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.c3f229f9ac04906ac631.js></script></body></html>
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

What could be the reason?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have alot of tags that can be self closing which will lower the amount of angle brackets to cause problems. Also I noticed that your css reference seemed odd and that your Javascript references were in the body (Doesn't matter but I put them in the head). Try this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>

<title>iStaging LiveTour</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/app.b96fc026269e85d4507be6f2804573f0.css">.
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.e3bed1667f2313b8b537.js />
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.9a48bc75d44e45d7cd37.js />
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.c3f229f9ac04906ac631.js />

</head>
<body>

<div id=app />

</body>
</html>
```